# unshifting to ng-repeat array not working while using orderBy

Tags: angularjs

Here is my problem. I've got a comment roll thats using ng-repeat to display the content of a comment array. When the user submits a comment I wan't to unshift to that array in order to display the most recent comment at the top of the list. This works perfectly, but when I add the orderBy filter to the repeat the new comment is applied to the bottom of the repeat.

Here is the comment array HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter:{page_id:raceID} | orderBy:'id':'reverse' track by comment.id ">
    <li>{{comment.id}}</li>
    <li>{{comment.page_id}}</li>
    <li>{{comment.user_name}}</li>
    <li>{{comment.comment_copy}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the corresponding Controller:

```
        $scope.comment = new newComments({page_id:3, comment_copy:'test comment copy'});

        $scope.comment.$save(function(data) {
            $scope.comments.unshift($scope.comment);
            console.log($scope.comment.id);
        });
```

.....

Comment: Does ordering before filtering make the difference?

Comment: Problem still persists, unshifting onto array will show up at the bottom. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've posted the answer to my own question below, I just created a custom filter that reverses the array instead of using angular's built in orderBy. Worked just as expected. If you have any other suggestion let me know and I'll try them.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for posting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scrapped the

```
orderBy:'id':'reverse'
```

and instead used a custom filer left on another post here, [Angular ng-repeat in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266671/angular-ng-repeat-in-reverse). Here is the custom function

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

Now the most recent comment was still not showing up at the top of the page so I had to change from unshift to push. This worked perfectly. Here's the code:

```
$scope.comment.$save(function(data) {
    $scope.comments.push($scope.comment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things are wrong in your original post:

1. `orderBy:'id':'reverse'` should be `orderBy:'id':reverse`, where `reverse` is a boolean (so either replace it by a variable available on the scope, or by a hard-coded true/false). Currently, it defaults to `undefined` and is interpreted as `false`.
2. In your controller code, the field `comment`.`id` is not assigned. It will default to `undefined` and that's the reason sorting does not work as expected.

Additionally:

1. Array `unshift` or `push` will not make a difference in your use case if you correct the aforementioned and the `orderBy` function is invoked.
2. In my experience in Angular 1.5.8, `track by $index` in fact prevented the `orderBy` function from working. Replacing it by a unique identifier on the object to be repeated, i.e. `track by comment.id` is preferred. In terms of performance, they should be analogous. Not using the `track by` clause is the slowest option though. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me, would love to know how it affects performance though:

change:

```
track by comment.id
```

to:

```
track by $index
```

both `unshift()` and `push()` should work now, but again, not sure about how much it slows down the DOM regeneration.