# Animate new elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I am using AngularJS and I am trying to animate on enter the new elements in my array:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
  {{ obj.name }}
</div>
```

But there is a trouble with the way I renew my array: I am doing it with `http.get` and I am not pushing some new element to my object but totally renew it like here:

```
$http.get('/some/url').success(function(objects){
  $scope.objects = objects;
});
```

So is there any way to handle animation in this case or do I need to change the way I renew my array?

Comment: I tried looping the results and push them into $scope.objects, but that was too fast and I didn't see the animation occur .... if there was an option to delay a bit inside the "for loop" then I could really tell if it's happening at all :D

Answer (score 2):

If you use ngAnimate, you should be able to animate the ng-enter class without an issue. Check out this plunker...

http://plnkr.co/edit/oCLzLHbDLtNT8G8rKFJS?p=preview

I am setting a 2 second delay and then completely replacing the array. The animations still work as expected. Using Angular version 1.2+, simply include the ngAnimate module in your main application module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Give your ng-repeat elements a css class, for example 'animate'. And attach css animations, when the ng-enter, ng-leave classes are added by angular

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave {
...
}
.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, 
.animate.ng-leave{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Here's a different working example of what Charlie Martin posted above. https://jsfiddle.net/hyga3rf1/

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I came across it and thought I would put in my $0.02

Instead of replacing the object with the new list just to get a few new elements, instead push just the new elements into the back of the array, and then have the array displayed in [your ng-repeat in reverse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266671/angular-ng-repeat-in-reverse) This way when the new items come in they go in one at a time, allowing them to be animated.

```
$http.get('/some/url')
.success(function(objects){
  for(o in objects){
    if(!$scope.objects[o]){
      $scope.objects.push(objects[o]);
    }
  }
});
```