# Filter is not applying when adding object to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have an `ng-repeat` that contains a filter on one of the items in the repeated list. The filter works fine except when I add an item to the `ng-repeat`ed array. The `ng-repeat` looks something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <div>{{post.created | formatTimestamp}}</div>
    <div>{{post.message}}</div>
</div>
```

The `formatTimestamp` filter definitely works, and is probably too long to list here, so I'll omit it. The problem I'm having is that when a user makes a new post I `unshift` the new post in to the `posts` array. The post shows up as expected, but the `formatTimestamp` filter doesn't apply. When I refresh the page, then the filter does work. Something about `unshift`ing the new post prevents the filter from applying. I tried using `scope.$digest()`, but that didn't solve the problem. The handling of the new post is inside a directive and looks like this:

```
// store the new post in the database, etc.
scope.posts.unshift(data);
scope.$digest(); // didn't have any effect
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the original value of `post.created` is shown?

Comment: I think we need a little more code. I can't reproduce the problem from what you've given us. I tried to reproduce it here, but it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/qothgzkg/

Comment: The date is displayed, but it isn't run through the filter. The filter does work, however, when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

if not wrong you want to print the list in reverse order (i.e. last entry on top)? 
did you tried printing the list in **reverse order** as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266671/angular-ng-repeat-in-reverse) and use `scope.posts.push(data)` to add a new entry.

maybe a workaround but if you think `unshift` is a problem than you can give this a try. 
for better debugging though I would prefer to see more of your code