# Reverse order of items pulled from database in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb

I have a 'photos' array in a MongoDB database that is updated as users take photos on Instagram at certain locations.
I push information about each new photo to this 'photos' array, so the most recent photo is on the end of the array. This is where my issue arises.

I use ng-repeat to display these photos in my view. The obvious problem is that the most recent photo ends up at the end of the page rather than the beginning.

What is the easiest way to reverse the order ng-repeat displays in? I have not been able to find a built-in filter that does this.

Comment: You have tried `| reverse`?

Comment: Please chcek this answer [link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266671/angular-ng-repeat-in-reverse]

Comment: The below answer was the best solution for me. Changing `$scope.photos = response.photos` to `$scope.photos = response.photos.reverse()` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reverse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) the array after you get the data.

```
data.reverse();
```

HTML:

```
<element ng-repeat="data" ...
```

You can also write a filter to do that. There is no built-in filter for reverse AFAIK.