# Display items in reverse order from Firebase in ng-repeat

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

My issue is similar to the SO question below

[Reverse order of items pulled from database in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694718/reverse-order-of-items-pulled-from-database-in-ng-repeat)

HOWEVER, I am using the following method to bind all the transactions for a specific AccountID

```js
var syncObject = $firebaseObject(fb.child("members/" + fbAuth.uid + "/accounts/" + $scope.AccountId));
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
```

The difference from the SO question mentioned above and mine is that I'm using the `$firebaseObject` to bind the data (three-way data binding).

So how can I show the list of transactions in reverse order? I want to show the most recent transaction at the top of the view

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just some thoughts: since it's a *list* of transactions, maybe you should use `firebaseArray` instead of `firebaseObject`. Additionally, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266671/angular-ng-repeat-in-reverse) will be of use.

Comment: As described in the docs, $firebaseArray is for binding collections and $firebaseObject is not. You can get by without $bindTo. Just call $save() when you make changes and use the tools appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using $firebaseArray in this case as it'll allow you to sort however you want:

**Javascript**

```js
var ref = fb.child("members/" + fbAuth.uid + "/accounts/" + $scope.AccountId);

$scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

**HTML**

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="child in data | orderBy:'FIELD_TO_SORT_BY':true>
    <!-- other elements -->
</div>
```