# Display data in ng-repeat once

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "country": "Philippines"
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Marsha",
    "country": "Philippines"
  },
  {
   "id": "3",
    "name": "Peter",
    "country": "Philippines"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Kang",
    "country": "Philippines"
  }
]
```

What I want is to display it in using ng-repeat but since all the countries are the same, I want to display the country only once. How can I possibly do that? My html file is like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in citizens">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-model="item.id">
        {{item.id}}
    </label>
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-model="item.name">
        {{item.name}}
    </label>
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-model="item.country">
        {{item.country}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to Show every Country once, what should be `id` and `name` for Country `Philippines`?

Comment: I only want to display the country only once since they are the same

Comment: You can use  groupBy: Country, i think

Comment: Where will I put the groupBy?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473736/angularjs-groupby-orderby

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the label as the following:

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-model="item.country" ng-show="$index>0 && item.country!=citizens[$index-1].country">
    {{item.country}}
</label>
```

The ng-show will check if the previous item's country is not same as the current item's country , then only show the label.
**Note :** `$index>0` will make sure the first item is skipped for this check.

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-if condition on the label where we display country name.

```
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ng-bind = "item.country" 
   ng-model="item.country" ng-if="$index>0 && item.country!=citizens[$index-1].country">
  </label>
```

here is the plunker [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hyy84TuIh3K0nN3cVzC0?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this plunker but it did not display the "Philippines" I need to display the value of the country once since they are all from the same country

Comment: Its still the same. It's not displaying the country "Philippines" once as a header

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the requirement you have to use the group by filter in angular ng-repeat.

I have attached the code snipped along with

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in citizens | groupBy: 'country'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
        <div>Name: {{ item.name }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to include angular filter file in your script as well.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

Also inject the angular filter dependency in your ass like this

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter) for further details