# Reversing ng-repeat's order, iterating over anglefire array

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

Being new to Angular and Firebase, naturally AngleFire is giving me troubles. I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over a synced array, and I'd like to reverse the order it's displaying. I've tried '| reverse' as well as variations of that, sorting the array on the FireBase side, and copying the array into a local only array then reversing it; among more things than I can remember at this point.

JS adding data to array

```
ctrl.go = function() {
  console.log(ctrl.localArray);
  ctrl.localArray.$add(
    {
      name: ctrl.name,
      content: ctrl.content,
      time: new Date().getTime(),
    }
  );
  console.log(ctrl.localArray);
```

HTML w/ ng-repeat

```
  <span ng-repeat="localArray in ctrl.localArray">
        {{localArray.content}}<br>
        <p class="right">- {{localArray.name}} at {{localArray.time | date : "MMM d, h:mm a"}}</p>
  </span>
```

What needs to be done to have the ng-repeat display reversed to how it is?

Solution:

```
<span ng-repeat="localArray in ctrl.localArray.reverse()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method directly in template:

```
<span ng-repeat="localArray in ctrl.localArray.reverse()">
    {{localArray.content}}<br>
    <p class="right">- {{localArray.name}} at {{localArray.time | date : "MMM d, h:mm a"}}</p>
</span>
```

Or you can do it in controller before passing array to HTML.

Comment: I swear I tried that already, although it's worked beautifully.

Comment: How would I do so in the controller before passing the array to the HTML? I've tried using passing a different array to the HTML, which is set to ctrl.localArray.reverse() every time something is added to localArray, but then I couldn't get anything to be displayed with ngrepeat.

Comment: To answer your last comment -- You can use a custom filter. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15267754/1526037