# How can I do reverse in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this Js method but I can't to implement a reverse loop

```
$scope.organizeByMonth = function () {    
    for (var i in $scope.incidents) {

        var month = new Date($scope.incidents[i].upload_date).getMonth();    
        if (!monthIncidents[month]) {

            monthIncidents[month] = {    
                name: $scope.months[month],
                incidents: []
            };
        }
        var incident = $scope.incidents[i];    
        incident.index = i;    
        monthIncidents[month].incidents.push(incident);
    }
};
```

how can I show the same objects in reverse :/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea if $scope.incidents is an array (which it looks like it is because `push` is used for a similar name). If it is an array it can be easily reversed prior to iterating it; or the 'explicit for' form can be trivially used.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a reverse loop with the `for in` syntax - it also doesn't matter. Objects in JavaScript are unordered.

Comment: And maybe more to the point: the code is *probably* incorrectly using `for..in` for an array.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to a reverse for..in.. loop would be to get the object keys and iterate backwards over them:

```
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var keys = Object.keys(object);
for(var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(keys[i], object[keys[i]]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1oztmp2e/

Comment: Won't matter for an object, they're unordered!

Comment: Nothing stops you from ordering the keys with a sort call. It entirely depends on the OP and how he intends to use it.

Comment: You can't sort the keys, it could be interpreted differently depending on the browser.

Comment: Ofcourse you can. If we both refer to `var keys = Object.keys(object);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Again: `var keys = Object.keys(object);` is an array and arrays can be sorted.

Comment: Ahh - yeah, you can sort the keys - I was talking about the object itself

Comment: Yes, that's why I edited it in my prior comment but you were too fast replying :P

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to reverse the for loop? Is it only for display purpose?

If so, I am assuming you are using ng-repeat for displaying the records. Should that be the case, you can use [a custom reverse filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267754/4963159).

Or if you need the array reversed for a different reason, simply use [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) after populating the array