# condition for reverse in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

is it possible to have a condition in a ng-repeat section ? I want the list to be reversed if the condition is true

```
<td ng-repeat="dataset in something.datasets if(true) { reverse }">
```

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15267754/2435473) might help you

Comment: you can create a custom angularjs filter , https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pugonijedo/1/edit?html,js,output)

You don't need a condition, you can use a filter for this which is `orderBy`

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in vm.items | orderBy: item : vm.reverse'>
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

if `vm.reverse` is true, it will display in the reverse order.

Documentation for [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)